# Change all the same RGB colors of different forms/text

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I change a color that is applied to various forms (border or background) and text areas which are in groups?

For example, I have a group "BigBox1" with "icon1", "icon2", "text1" inside and a group "BigBox2" with "icon11", "icon22", "text11" inside.

These elements are all in the color RGB(153, 153, 255), "icon1" and "icon11" have their border in this color, "icons2" and "icon22" have their background in this color, "text1" and "text11" have their font in this color.

In my document, I also have other groups ("BigBox3", "BigBox4") with different colors but I would only like to change the color RGB(153, 153, 255) to RGB(50, 66, 115) without the need to select individually each element which currently has the color RGB(153, 153, 255).

I am looking for a macro that looks for a RGB color in a document (whenever it is - background, border, font) then change its RGB color to another one.

I tried this.

```vb
Sub changecolor ()
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find.Font
    .Format.Font.Color = RGB(153, 153, 255)
    .Replacement.Font.Color = RGB(50, 66, 115)
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working because `.Execute` isn't a method of `Font`

```
Sub changecolor ()
  With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Font.Color = RGB(153, 153, 255)
    .Replacement.Font.Color = RGB(50, 66, 115)
    .Format = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End Sub
```

To change the border and background colors of the shapes you will need to loop through every shape, and its group items, and check the existing color of each property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Timothy Rylatt. Unfortunately, "loop through every shape, and its group items, and check the existing color of each property" is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @ValentinFeydel - there isn't any other way. `Find` only works on text.